# Barium ion ASTRID versus Heisenberg's quote

Tags: quantum-mechanics

Many of the users here may know "Astrid," the name given to the first isolated ion. It is a Barium ion. So a quantum particle is not an illusion. It has an objective reality. It has a finite mass and finite dimension. Its photo is attached below.

[image]

Now see Heisenberg's quote:

> The invisible elementary particle of modern physics does not have the
>   property of occupying space any more than it has properties like color
>   and solidity. Fundamentally, it is not a material structure in space
>   and time but only a symbol that allows the laws of nature to be
>   expressed in especially simple form.

Even though above picture is not of elementary particles, Astrid is definitely a quantum particle. In other words, any theoretical physicist would apply quantum mechanics to study it, and not classical mechanics. So

- Is Heisenberg's quote no longer valid?, or
- Is Heisenberg's quote still a fact of life?

Answer (score 2):

The photograph was taken by Hans Dehmelt in 1974. Anyone interested in the work of Hans Dehmelt should read [his Nobel lecture available here](http://www.nobelprize.org/nobel_prizes/physics/laureates/1989/dehmelt-lecture.pdf).

Re your question about Heisenberg's quote: the quote doesn't apply because this is a picture of an ion not an elementary particle. The ion has a physical size courtesy of being a bound state of many elementary particles. The elementary particles themselves are [rather more elusive objects](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/41676/why-do-physicists-believe-that-particles-are-pointlike).

You should also note that this is not an **image** of a barium ion. It is the light scattered from a barium ion. The ion itself is far too small to produce an optical image. The resolution of the photograph is around a micron and the ion itself is 10,000 times smaller than this.

Comment: Fisrt thing: Elementary particles are not elusive, but illusive, according to Heisenberg. There is difference between words elusive and illusive. Second thing: then the barium ion which is made of these illusive particles must be also illusive. If something is illusive, how can light scatter from it ?